# aptana creates an empty django project

Tags: django, aptana, pydev

I am using aptana 3.3.1, django 1.2.7, python 2.7

when i create a new django project in aptana i get an empty project.

No settings.py no manage.py etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.
It is the name of the project, test cant be used as the name of the project because it is the name of an existing python module.